# Ubuntu not booting after hard drive failure

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have a 4yo Lenovo IdeaFlex5 running Ubuntu 23.10, with umis rpjtj512mee1owx storage (some say it's SSD, but in ubuntu it was always `/dev/nvme...` so NVMe). It worked perfectly fine until it froze out of the blue. Rebooting led to a terminal asking me to run `fsck` manually, which gave me 1000s of errors, I pressed yes to all. Rerunning `fsck` gave no errors.

Rebooting again gave me `kernel panic - libaudit.so.1 has an invalid ELF header`. The problem occurred even if I choose recovery mode. I booted from a live USB, mounted my hard drive, backed up my data (which was luckily unaffected), and replaced `libaudit.so.1` with a valid copy from the removable storage, only to get the same error with a different `.so` file, so I replaced it too.

Now, if I boot my machine (without live USB) I don't get a kernel panic, but still get a lot of errors and end up in a recovery terminal. How can I recover my Ubuntu? Despite backing up my data I would like things to go back to the way it was, if possible.

I should add that I have a Windows partition (dual boot) that's working fine on the same hard drive, so perhaps it's an encouraging sign about my hardware.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; so we can only be generic in what we advise, but your details show a likely hardware issue; so I'd check drive health (SMART), RAM, PSU etc.. as to what caused the issue to begin with. Next I'd likely restore your system from your backups (*once you've proven hardware is valid*), though if a Desktop system a non-destructive re-install is also possible (*but you gave no clues as to product & release; so do whatever is appropriate for your unstated system*)

Comment: FYI:  If not a hardware issue (*you mention dual boot; though windows will be on a different part of your disk thus may not yet be impacted if it's a dying drive*), it can also be the consequence of a poor decision by an operator with `sudo` privileges in a prior session by installing incorrect packages intended for a different Ubuntu release or different system, thus you could also explore system logs once your product/release is known & look for evidence of poor install decisions in logs too. This exploration can be done using *live* media